# How to index your own defined type of list in F#

Tags: f#

Excuse me if it's a dumb question, but I'm new with f# and couldn't find anything on this. I'm working on a school assignment to make scrabble words, and am trying to define a function that retrieves a point value of a specific (letter, value) combination, given a word, and the index of the letter. The type word has to be defined as  `type word = (char * int) list`

I define the type word, and create a word "Hello"

```
type word = Word of (char * int) list

let hello = Word (['H', 4; 'E', 1; 'L', 1; 'L', 1; 'O', 2])
```

How can I access the point value at a given index? I know indexing of lists can be done with `some_list.[index]`.
But when trying to do this

```
let squareFun (w:word) (pos:int) =
    let pair = w.[pos]
    fst pair
```

`w.[pos]` gives the error

```
The field, constructor or member 'Item' is not defined.(39: typecheck)
```

So, how can I access the tuple in my word type? The function squareFun in the example below should return 2, as the character 'O' at index 4, has value 2.

```
squareFun hello 4
```

Comment: If you need random access you should use an array, not a list. Lists aren't appropriate for indexed access.

Comment: word is not a list. it is a union type.

Comment: However... are you sure you want to store the points per letter in that way?

Comment: `type word = (char * int) list` and `type word = Word of (char * int) list` are different; which one do you want?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov ahhhh ok, that makes more sense. if I define word as ```type word = (char * int) list```, how can I define hello? 
```let hello = word (['H', 4; 'E', 1; 'L', 1; 'L', 1; 'O', 2])``` Is not working.

Comment: Just `let hello = ['H', 4; 'E', 1; 'L', 1; 'L', 1; 'O', 2]`.

Comment: Is there any point in defining type word then, as we're not specifying it in the definition of hello? Does f# know somehow that hello is a word?

Comment: If you're using a type abbreviation, F# won't know the difference between the two types. You can do `let hello : Word = ...` to specify it explicitly, but it won't change the behavior. Still, defining the type may help when writing code, as it ensure's you're always using the same representation for a word. By using a single case union type, you could ensure that only "correct" words are created, e.g. not [ ',', -4 ] or similar. See the link in my answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write that "The type word has to be defined as `type word = (char * int) list`", but then you define `type word = Word of (char * int) list`. See the difference? That's what's causing you trouble. If you remove `Word of` it'll work. You'll need to remove `Word` from the definition of `hello` as well.

Alternatively, if you wish to keep the definition of `word` as is, you can deconstruct the `w` parameter instead, by replacing `w: word` with `Word w`. Again everything should work.

So the big question of course is; what's the difference? When `word` is defined by `type word = (char * int) list`, it's a [type abbreviation](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-abbreviations/). That means you're basically giving some type another name. The new type will have all the same members as the old one - also them `Item` member, which is required for indexing the type. When `word` is defined by `type word = Word of (char * int) list` instead, it's a [single case union type](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/), which is its own type alltogether, and hence doesn't have any of the underlying types members.

Comment: By the way, you could of course add an `Item` member to your own type as well, like so: `type word = Word of (char * int) list with member this.Item(i) = let (Word w) = this in w.[i]`

Answer (score 1):

Your word type is not a list. It is a single case union type.
Therefore you need to Deconstruct it first.

```ml
let (Word letters) = hello
letters.[0]
```